# how to fetch place from this

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a table name app_places having place details 
[see image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HL50.jpg)

PROBLEM: I want to fetch data only once and want to show in json format for same place_id

Here is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT place_id FROM `app_places` ";
$check= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $place_id=$row['place_id'];

    $sql1="SELECT * FROM app_places where place_id='".$place_id."' limit 1";
    //var_dump($sql1);
    $check2= mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($check2,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        $json []= $result;
    }

    $json1 []= array("place"=>$json);
}

echo json_encode($json1);
```

I need following output

```
[
 {
    placeName="Name",
    placeId="11",
    placePrimaryImage="http://www.gettyimages.in/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg",
   .
   .
   .
```

But the output come from this not as per my requirement Thanks in advance please help me .

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/
Also, you're not telling us what output you're actually getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = array();
$sql = "SELECT description, place_id, image FROM app_places GROUP BY place_id";
$check = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check))
{
    $json[] = $result;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```